What are indirect and common cause links?
This question is about the PCMCI method (as described by Runge et al 2019) for finding causal relationships in time series data.
The 2nd part of the process, called Momentary Conditional Independence (MCI) involves independence testing of the target ($X^3_t$ in the below example) with its causal parent ($X^1_{ t−2}$) conditioned on the causal parents of both:

The MCI test (Fig. 3C) then addresses  false positive control for the
highly-interdependent time series case: As an example, for testing $X^1_{t−2} \rightarrow X ^3_{ t}$ , the conditions $ \hat{\mathscr{P}}(X^3_ t )$ (blue boxes in Fig. 3B) are sufficient to establish
conditional independence (Markov property), that is, to identify
indirect and common cause links.

For reference, Fig 3B is below:

I'm confused by the statement that this part of the process "[identifies] indirect and common cause links". What does this mean and how does this step achieve that?

The phrase

... $\hat{\mathcal{P}}(X_t^j)$ are sufficient to establish conditional independence (Markov property), that is, to identify indirect and common cause links...

refers to the fact that the true parent set of $X_t^j$, denoted as ${\mathcal{P}}(X_t^j)$, trivially $d$-separates it from all its non-descendants, including $X_{t-\tau}^i$ for any $\tau>0$ (and any variable index $i$). Therefore, if the conditional independence of $X_t^j$ and $X_{t-\tau}^i$ given the putative parent set $\hat{\mathcal{P}}(X_t^j)$ (containing only variables pre-$t$) is rejected, it indicates that there are some unaccounted parents of $X_t^j$ in open paths to $X_{t-\tau}^i$. Let $Y$ represent such a missing parent. There are two possible structures representing an open path: (i) common cause link (fork or confounding structure): $X_{t-\tau}^i \leftarrow Y \rightarrow $ $X_t^j$; or (ii) an indirect causal link: $X_{t-\tau}^i \rightarrow Y \rightarrow X_t^j$. Thus, this aspect of the test serves to identify (or detect) the presence of such links.
